# Java memory consistency for Executor's worker threads

Tags: java, multithreading, memory, executor, happens-before

According to [javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Executor.html), an implementation of `Executor` must comply with:

> Memory consistency effects: Actions in a thread (*A*) prior to submitting a Runnable object to an Executor happen-before its execution begins, perhaps in another thread (*B*).

Pheraps due to my poor English, it is not clear to me which memory-consistency relation is guaranteed (if any) between *B* and another potential thread *C* subsequently submitted by *A* to the same Executor. I hope the following example will clarify my doubt.

```
import java.util.concurrent.Executor;
import java.util.concurrent.Executors;

class ExecutorTestClass {

    int a = 1;
    volatile boolean isDone = false;
    MyRunnable mr1 = new MyRunnable("One");
    MyRunnable mr2 = new MyRunnable("Two");

    class MyRunnable implements Runnable {
    private final String name;

    MyRunnable(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        System.out.println(name + ": " + ExecutorTestClass.this.a++);
        isDone = true; // signal that addition has been performed
        while (true) {
        try {
            Thread.sleep(5); // busy thread
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        }
        }
    }

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
    ExecutorTestClass emc = new ExecutorTestClass();
    Executor executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(2);
    executor.execute(emc.mr1); // run the first MyRunnable
    while (!emc.isDone) {
    } // when stop spinning emc.a == 2 for this thread
    executor.execute(emc.mr2); // is emc.a == 2 guaranteed?

    }

}
```

Is guaranteed that `emc.a == 2` for the thread executing `emc.mr2.run()`? (In my tests that is always true, but...yes, they are tests) 
If not, is there interface in the official API that ensure that `emc.a == 2`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No it is not guaranteed because you change value of `emc.a` in one thread but submit `Runnable` from another thread. If you submit second runnable from first runnable after it set value to 2 then memory consistency effect from JavaDoc will be applicable.

But in your example usage of `volatile` variable `isDone` will do the trick even without taking into account that note from JavaDoc.
Since you first increment `emc.a`, then set new value to `isDone` and then check `isDone` it sill establish **happens before** relation and second runnable will always see updated value.